# How to extract HTML table data using Java from a website?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, screen-scraping

I've got this website:
[www.bloomberg.com](http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/movers/ftse-100/)

And I want to extract the name and price for each company listed; i've looked around but the following code i found doesn't work?

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;



public class testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/movers/ftse-100/").get();


    for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=index_members_table dual_border_data_table market_sortable_table alt_rows_stat_table]")) {
         for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            Elements tds = row.select("td");
            System.out.println(tds.get(0).text() + "->" + tds.get(1).text());
         }

    }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your link does not work (http://http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/movers/ftse-100/)

Comment: Try removing first `http://` in the URL in `Jsoup.connect` call.

Comment: Your link does not work. It should be http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/movers/ftse-100

Answer (score 1):

(1) URL is invalid (has extra scheme) (2) There are `<tr>s` with no `<td>s` (ex. headers)

```
        ::::
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks/movers/ftse-100/").get();

        for (Element table : doc
                .select("table[class=index_members_table dual_border_data_table market_sortable_table alt_rows_stat_table]")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
                Elements tds = row.select("td");
                if (tds.isEmpty()) { // Header <tr> with only <th>s
                    continue;
                }
        ::::
```